# Properly handling TypeScript's weak type detection

Tags: typescript

Given this simplified example, what's the proper way to express that the function `makeAnimalBark` can accept any animal but only makes the barking ones bark.

```
interface Dog {
    bark: () => void
}

interface Cat {
    meow: () => void
}

interface PotentiallyBarkingAnimal {
    bark?: () => void
}

// Without `A` extending from something that has a `bark`
// property, TS complains that `bark` doesn't exist on `A`.

function makeAnimalBark<A extends PotentiallyBarkingAnimal>(animal: A) {
    if (animal && animal.bark)
        animal.bark()
}

makeAnimalBark<Dog>({
    bark: () => { }
})

// Here, TS complains that `Cat` has no properties
// in common with `PotentiallyBarkingAnimal`.

makeAnimalBark<Cat>({
    meow: () => { }
})
```

I understand why I'm seeing the error but I'm not sure as to the right way to handle this type of situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Without `A` extending from something that has a `bark`
// property, TS complains that `bark` doesn't exist on `A`.
```

That is because you are typing `bark` as being optional

```
interface PotentiallyBarkingAnimal {
    // remove the ? to make bark mandatory
    bark?: () => void
}
```

```
// Here, TS complains that `Cat` has no properties
// in common with `PotentiallyBarkingAnimal`.
```

Well that's true, right? if you look at it `Cat`s interface, it has no shared properties (`bark`) with `PotentiallyBarkingAnimal`. You need to let `PotentiallyBarkingAnimal` know about `meow`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. While it's true that there are no shared properties, it's perfectly safe to call the function with a `Cat`. That's what I'm having a hard time grasping - the function doesn't care about any other properties but `bark` so why do the objects need to have shared properties at all? I would think that as long as `Cat` didn't have an incompatible `bark` property there would be no issues calling the function with it.